# Is it possible to access Uploadcare CDN over https?

Tags: uploadcare

I upload my images using Uploadcare widget embedded in CKEditor, but my pages are https and I get browser warning because images are received over plain http. Tried to manually replace http with https in Uploadcare url, but that doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes!](https://www.google.com/search?q=uploadcare+https) You just need to [use a different base domain name](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/cdn/):

> You can use `https` for `ucarecdn.com` domain. This feature is experimental:
>   `https://ucarecdn.com/:uuid/`
>   Please note, we do not support `https` for `www.ucarecdn.com` domain as well as `http` for `ucarecdn.com`.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure widget to use the HTTPS domain (`ucarecdn.com`) via the [`UPLOADCARE_CDN_BASE`](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/widget/#data-cdn-base) setting.

Please note, if you are using Instagram as a source, some images will be loaded over HTTP, because Instagram doesn't have HTTPS for it's images.

Comment: Looks like Instagram [*may* soon support HTTPS](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2357779/instagram-to-use-https-following-discovery-of-gaping-security-hole-in-ios-app).